# stuck in finding $\frac{d(\sin^{-1}(x))}{dx}$

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

what is wrong with the following reasoning?
$$\sin(\sin^{-1}(x))=x$$
This is of the form $f(g(x))=h(x)$. Then, by implicit differentiation:
$$(f(g(x)))'=f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)=h'(x)               $$
Or in this case:
$$\cos(\sin^{-1}(x))\frac{d(\sin^{-1}(x))}{dx} = 1$$
Then $$\frac{d(\sin^{-1}(x))}{dx} = \frac{1}{\cos(\sin^{-1}(x))}$$
However I do not think this is correct. I wonder if I made a conceptual mistake in the implicit differentiation. Perhaps there are some extra steps needed to get to the result $$\frac{d(\sin^{-1}(x))}{dx} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$
If anyone could help me out that would be awesome! Thanks in advance.

Comment: This reasoning looks copacetic to me in the domain of the arcsine function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note we are making the usual assumptions on $x$ here.

Note that since $\sin(\arcsin x)=x$ and $\cos^2t+\sin^2t=1$ we have:$$\cos(\arcsin x)^2+\sin(\arcsin x)^2=1\\\cos(\arcsin x)^2=1-\sin(\arcsin x)^2\\\cos(\arcsin x)^2=1-x^2\\\cos(\arcsin x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$$
Can you see now?

Comment: Ah thanks, this is what I needed to finish the derivation!

Answer (score 1):

Let $y=\arcsin x=\sin^{-1}x$. Then $x=\sin y$, and so diffrentiating both sides of this equality w.r.t. $x$ and using chain rule we have $1=\cos y\frac{dy}{dx}$. Solving for $\frac {dy}{dx}$ and using the fact that $\cos y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$, (from the right triangle), we get $\frac {dy}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}\sin^{-1}x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$.